# Valores iniciais de uma média móvel exponencial no python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Olá,

estou tentando implementar o cálculo de uma média móvel exponencial com o pacote pandas do python.
Eu sei que exitem diversas maneiras de ponderação exponencial para uma média móvel, mas a que eu estou interessado é expressa em pseudocódigo para uma série de dados `y_i's` como:

```
MME_i = ((y_i - MME_i-1) * k) + MME_i-1
```

Onde `i` é a posição dos dados, `k` é definido pelo número de períodos (`n`) da média como: `k = 2 / (1 + n)`. O cálculo das médias começa a partir do enésimo valor e usa-se como aproximação para o primeiro valor da média `MME_i-1` uma média simples dos `n's` primeiros valores.

Nessa aproximação inicial que está meu problema, usando a função pré-construída do pacote pandas `Series.ewm` eu não consigo ajustar essa forma de aproximação dos valores iniciais. Tentei ligar e desligar a opção de 'adjust' e não consegui os resultados que pretendidos.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dados = np.array([[22.17,21.18],[23.08,21.01],[22.68,20.63],[22.22,20.26],[20.85,19.9],[20.19,19.73],[21.58,19.64],[19.63,19.29],[21.95,19.23],[19.18,18.73],[18.18,18.65],[15.01,18.73],[17.39,19.41],[18.53,19.78],[15.7,20.01],[15.4,20.79],[16.05,21.77],[13.95,22.81],[18,24.42],[15.99,25.59],[21.5,27.33],[24.95,28.39],[28.09,29.02],[31,29.19],[30.5,28.86],[29.81,28.56],[31.47,28.33],[31.4,27.76],[32.41,27.1],[28.95,26.13],[29,25.62],[28.85,25],[28.66,np.nan],[28.16,np.nan],[25.77,np.nan],[23.66,np.nan],[23.18,np.nan],[23.63,np.nan],[23.63,np.nan],[23.83,np.nan],[23.02,np.nan],[24.03,np.nan],[23.61,np.nan]])
df = pd.DataFrame(dados, columns = ['Dados','MME_12_controle'])
df = df.iloc[::-1]
n = 12
df['MME_12'] = df.Dados.ewm(span = n ,min_periods = n , adjust=False).mean()
print(df)
```

Onde 'Dados' são os valores para calcular a média, 'MME_12_controle' é a média calculada pelo método descrito (arredondados em 2 casas decimais) e 'MME_12' os valores calculados com a função [Series.ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ewm.html#pandas.Series.ewm).

Pergunta: há uma maneira de calcular esse método de média móvel exponencial usando as bibliotecas do Pandas ou Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi por que minha pergunta foi negativada. Mas consegui depois de algum tempo calcular a média móvel exponencial iniciando com uma aproximação de média aritmética para o primeiro termo e usando a função pré-construída `.ewm`. Espero que possa ser útil para mais alguém, segue o código:

```
df['MME_12'] = pd.Series(data = df['Dados'].iloc[:n].mean(), index = [df['Dados'].index[n-1]]).append(df['Dados'].iloc[n:]).ewm(alpha=(2/(1+n)), adjust = False).mean()
```